# Merge nodes that share attributes

Tags: python, graph, mapping, networkx

**EDITED**

I really need help from Networkx/graph experts.

Let us say I have the following data frames and I would like to convert these data frames to graphs. Then I would like to map the two graphs with corresponding nodes based on description and priority attributes.

df1

```
From   description    To         priority 
10        Start      20, 50         1
20        Left       40             2 
50        Bottom     40             2
40        End        -              1
```

df2

```
From   description    To      priority 
60        Start      70,80       1
70        Left       80, 90      2 
80        Left       100         2
90        Bottom     100         2
100        End        -          1
```

I just converted the two data frames and created a graph (g1, and g2).

And then I am trying to match the nodes based on their description and priority for only once. for example `10/60, 40/100, 50/90` but not `20/70, 20/80, and 70/80`. `20` has three conditions to be mapped which are not what I want. Because I would like to map nodes for only once unless I would like to put them as a single node and mark the node as red to differentiate.

A node should only be mapped for only once means, for example, if I want to map 10, it has priority `1` and description `Start` on the first graph and then find the same priority and description on the second graph. For this, 60 is there. There are no other nodes other than 60. But if we take `20` on the first graph, it has priority 2 and description `left`. On the second graph, there are two nodes with priority `2` and description `left` which is `70 and 80`. This creates confusion. I cannot map 20 twice like `20/70 and 20/80`. But I would like to put them as a single node as shown below on the sample graph.

I am expecting the following result.

[image: ![enter image description here]

To get the above result, I tried it with the following python code.

```
mapped_list= []

for node_1, data_1 in g1.nodes(data=True):
    for node_2, data_2 in g2.nodes(data=True):

        if (((g1.node[node_1]['priority']) == (g2.node[node_2]['priority'])) & 
                    ((g1.node[node_1]['description']) == (g2.node[node_2]['description']))
                   ):
                    if (node_1 in mapped_list) & (node_2 in mapped_list): // check of if the node exist on the mapped_list
                        pass
                    else:    
                        name = str(node_1) + '/' + str(node_2)
                        mapped_list.append((data_1["priority"], data_1["descriptions"], node_1, name))
                        mapped_list.append((data_2["priority"], data_2["descriptions"], node_2, name))
```

Can anyone help me to achieve the above result shown on the figure /graph/? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd go about this instead, is to build a new graph taking the [`nx.union`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.union.html) of both graphs, and then "combine" together the *start* and *end* nodes that share attributes using [`contracted_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html).

Let's start by creating both graphs from the dataframes:

```
df1 = df1.drop('To',1).join(df1.To.str.replace(' ','').str.split(',').explode())
df2 = df2.drop('To',1).join(df2.To.str.replace(' ','').str.split(',').explode())

g1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1.iloc[:-1,[0,3]].astype(int), 
                             source='From', target='To', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
g2 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2.iloc[:-1,[0,3]].astype(int), 
                             source='From', target='To', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

df1_node_ix = df1.assign(graph='graph1').set_index('From').rename_axis('nodes')
nx.set_node_attributes(g1, values=df1_node_ix.description.to_dict(), 
                       name='description')
nx.set_node_attributes(g1, values=df1_node_ix.priority.to_dict(), 
                       name='priority')
nx.set_node_attributes(g1, values=df1_node_ix.graph.to_dict(), 
                       name='graph')

df2_node_ix = df2.assign(graph='graph2').set_index('From').rename_axis('nodes')
nx.set_node_attributes(g2, values=df2_node_ix.description.to_dict(), 
                       name='description')
nx.set_node_attributes(g2, values=df2_node_ix.priority.to_dict(), 
                       name='priority')
nx.set_node_attributes(g2, values=df2_node_ix.graph.to_dict(), 
                       name='graph')
```

Now by taking the [`nx.union`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.union.html) of both graphs, we have:

```
g3 = nx.union(g1,g2)

from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
pos=graphviz_layout(g3, prog='dot')
nx.draw(g3, pos=pos, 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=1500, 
        node_color='red', 
        arrowsize=20)
```

[image]

What we can do now is come up with some data structure which we can later use to easily combine the pairs of nodes that share attributes. For that we can sort the nodes by their description. Sorting them will enable us to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group consecutive equal pairs of nodes, which we can then easily combine using [`nx.contrated_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html), and then just overwrite on the same previous graph. The nodes can be relabeled as specified in the question with [`nx.relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html):

```
from itertools import groupby

g3_node_view = g3.nodes(data=True)
sorted_by_descr = sorted(g3_node_view, key=lambda x: x[1]['description'])
node_colors = dict()
colors = {'Bottom':'saddlebrown', 'Start':'lightblue', 
          'Left':'green', 'End':'lightblue'}
all_graphs = {'graph1', 'graph2'}

for _, grouped_by_descr in groupby(sorted_by_descr, 
                                   key=lambda x: x[1]['description']):
    for _, group in groupby(grouped_by_descr, key=lambda x: x[1]['priority']):
        grouped_nodes = list(group)
        nodes = [i[0] for i in grouped_nodes]
        graphs = {i[1]['graph'] for i in grouped_nodes}

        # check if there are two nodes that share attributes
        # and both belong to different graphs
        if len(nodes)==2 and graphs==all_graphs:
            # contract both nodes and update graph
            g3 = nx.contracted_nodes(g3, *nodes)
            # define new contracted node name and relabel
            new_node = '/'.join(map(str, nodes))
            g3 = nx.relabel_nodes(g3, {nodes[0]:new_node})
            node_colors[new_node] = colors[grouped_nodes[0][1]['description']]
        else:
            for node in nodes:    
                node_colors[node] = 'red'
```

Which would give:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
pos=graphviz_layout(g3, prog='dot')
nx.draw(g3, pos=pos, 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=2500, 
        nodelist=node_colors.keys(),
        node_color=node_colors.values(), 
        arrowsize=20)
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for taking time to answer. I just applied your piece of code for a larger graph with an average of 30 nodes. But it couldn't work. Is that possible to extend the code that I tried above on the question?

Comment: Could you share the edge lists of the graphs? @kapital see if I can spot what could be the issue

Comment: Actually, In reality, I have four priorities (1, 2, 3, 4) and many descriptions in both graphs. The edge lists differ have different priorities and descriptions and I think it not easy to share all of them.

Comment: Looking into adapting your code. But, what do you mean with `match the nodes based on their description and priority for only once`? @Kapital

Comment: For only once means, let us say if we map 10 with 50 as (10/50), 10 or 50 shouldn't map with the other nodes. But if you see 20 it has two options with 60 and 70 (same prirority and descriptions) which is not what I want. When there such kind of possibility, I would like to put them as a single node. As your result is showed above.

Comment: So you want them in a single node, *only* when there are 2 nodes which share description and priority? @kapital

Comment: So for example if node 20, had a different description, you'd want to have 60 and 70 combined? @kapital

Comment: If 60 has a different description or priority, I would map 20 with 70 (20/70) and I would put 60 as a single node/

Comment: And 60 and 70 shouldn't be combined, since they are found on the same graph. To be able to map that should be in different graph.

Comment: So you only want to combine those that are in different graphs? @kapital

Comment: Okay another question, just to see if I get this right. Imagine there is another node `65` just like 60 and 70. What then? Does 20 combine with any of them? Or not since there is more than 1 option? @kapital

Comment: If ```20 and 65``` from the first graph and ```60 and 70``` from 2nd graph have the same priority and description then there is a kind ambiguity between them because I cannot decide which nodes I should map. So, the solution would be putting all of them as a single node again.

Comment: And what if 65 is in the second graph? @kapital Sorry for all these questions, but this seems complex. Lots of points to consider, I'd suggest you to update the answer with them so that people have a better idea

Comment: I would put it as a single node.

Comment: Because the match is not one to one. 20 has confusion to match with 60, 65, and 70.  In this case, I would like to put them as a single node all of them.

Comment: Okay I think I've got it, will update soon. On the meantime I think It'd make it much easier if you shared a more complete example reflecting some of the points we've discussed @kapital

Comment: More clarification is added now. I think my idea is clear now.

Comment: I don't get something. In the second graph, 70 connects with both 80 and 90. Why does it not connect to 90 in the result? @kapital

Comment: Is that correct and just my misunderstanding @Kapital ?

Comment: Indeed. You are right. there should be a connection. I did it manually and didn't realize it.

Comment: Okay here another (hopefully last) question,  since there's an edge connecting 60->70 *and* 60->80, should't that be the case too in the output graph too? @kapital

Comment: It's okay. You can ask. You are right. There should be a connection. ```80``` should connect with both ```70 and 60``` as well. I just connected manually and that is also a mistake. I think now you understood it well. Thanks for the correction!!

Comment: I've adapted what I had before to what we've been commenting. I believe using `contracted_nodes` is the way to go here and simplifies it quite a bit. Let me know if you want further details @kapital

Comment: Is this correct? ```graphs = {i[1]['graph'] for i in grouped_nodes}``` I am getting an error ```KeyError: 'graph' ```

Comment: Yes, make sure you create the graph as I have @kapital I've added a column specifying if a graph is either graph1 or 2

Comment: If that is not the case just add the "graph" attribute to the nodes @Kapital `nx.set_node_attributes(g1, values=df1_node_ix.graph.to_dict(), 
                       name='graph')`, for either graph 1 or 2

Comment: to be honest, I didn't use it but I gave you 50 points of bounty because you tried your best to help me. Many thanks, Sir.